# Is it possible to install kali linux operating system in mac book pro?

Tags: kali-linux, macbook-pro

i have macbook pro and I recently changed the harddrive. Am an Isp so i wanted to use kali linux as my operating system. The hard drive is new. Is it possible?

Comment: What research have you done so far? Why weren't the results suitable?

Comment: If you're an ISP and want to install Kali Linux on a workstation, I'm glad I'm not your customer.

Comment: @John - with a Mac & Kali, the problem isn't using it, it's getting it on there in the first place. [Google has a million references to it, but as the OP seems to have done no research, no-one so far seems inclined to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Might not be easy, and really not what Kali was intended to do, but I'm sure, given enough effort and persistence that it can be done. Just keep in mind that you'll probably spend days doing this, just to end up with a barely functioning system.

From [Kali's website](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/):

> If you are unfamiliar with Linux generally, if you do not have at least a basic level of competence in administering a system, if you are looking for a Linux distribution to use as a learning tool to get to know your way around Linux, or if you want a distro that you can use as a general purpose desktop installation, Kali Linux is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: I sometimes enjoy a solid, literal answer to a question. Is it possible? Yes. …Zero information about how to achieve it, but you can't deny it answers the question exactly as asked. ;))

Comment: What can I say, Kali questions bring it out in me

Comment: Yup - I often add the compulsory link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)